# Permissions to view files in a doc lib but not view/open/download

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions

Is there a way to set permissions on a folder in a document library - let's call it a Confidential folder - such that anyone can view the list of files in the folder but only authorised people can view/open/download them?

I have tried to use the in-built "View" permission level and it does not meet my requirement (it still allows the user to view and download).

Code/non-code solutions are invited.

I'm aware this question has been asked previously but I haven't seen an answer to it.

Comment: have you tried limited access permission level?

Comment: Is Limited Access actually a permission level? How can I use it to meet my requirements?

Comment: You want to restirct the user to view only but not open. that what i think may be work in your conditions. becuase this one dont have open item in it.

Comment: The built-in "View only" permission level also does not have "Open" permissions but users are still able to open files in the document library.

Comment: this one also does nto have the view items permission as well. SO best is try.

Comment: Sorry Waqas, I don't understand what it is you are suggesting. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: if you go to the site settings> site permissions > from ribbon you will see permission level. one of the permission level is limited access, which is assigned to Style Resource Reader group...I want you to add the user in that group and then add that group to you document library

Comment: You can't assign someone limited access, it is picked up automatically when permissions inheritance is broken somewhere. In this case the style resource readers you are asking him to add will still need a permission assigned to the group and you can't assign limited access.

Comment: PirateEric - that's what I thought. It seems there is no way to achieve this easily then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got around this issue by having permissions at item level rather than folder level.

Originally, permission inheritance was being broken on the folder and all files in the folder were inheriting permissions from the folder.

Now, the folder inherits permissions from its parent (the list) and the files within the folder all have inheritance broken on them with unique permissions on each one.

This allows me to give read/edit permissions to only the files in the folder that I choose. This is actually achieved with an event receiver. When someone uploads a file into this folder, the event receiver breaks inheritance on it immediately and gives read/edit permissions to the uploader. The uploader can then manually go in and give permissions to any further people they want to share the file with.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a group to put users in. When you create a group there are options for the different levels of permissions. One of the options is a restricted read. This may give you what you are looking for. It's at least worth a try.

Comment: Tried it - didn't work. The problem is the Restricted Read has the "View Items" permission assigned to it (which has this description: "View items in lists, documents in document libraries, and view Web discussion comments.") With this permission assigned users can see documents in a library AND open them in the browser (but not download them).